# How to get a .NET Cores configuration using IIS GetWebConfiguration?

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, web-administration

I'm creating a .NET Core 2.1 Web API project (with Angular 7 front-end) where I'm using the Microsoft.Web.Administration API to pull information from remote IIS web servers (mainly listing websites, applications, app-pools, etc.):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet

As a quick note, here is how I am instantiating a remote-IIS server object, a `ServerManager` object:

To create the `ServerManager` object (the IIS 'container' object, so-to-speak) I use one of the hidden constructors where I pass the remote IIS server's `applicationHost.config` file path to it (located at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` -- default location). I'm doing this because I receive COM-related issues when I use the `ServerManager.OpenRemote(string server_ip)` method.

Anyways, whenever I'm trying to use the ServerManager's, Site's, and Application's `GetWebConfiguration` methods to get the `Web.config` files for each IIS object, each of the aforementioned object's `GetWebConfig` methods fail. The app doesn't crash when I run my code, but upon object inspection in the debugger, this is the following error listed:

```
my_siteWebConfig.RootSectionGroup = 'my_siteWebConfig.RootSectionGroup' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
```

It looks like the `GetWebConfiguration` code is looking for the site/application's `web.config` file in an non-existent directory. Debugger shows that the `ConfigurationPathToEdit` equals `"MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/my_site"`. It's looking in the directory where the `applicationHost.Config` file is (the global IIS settings file location). However, my websites' & applications' `web.config` files are stored under the `D:\ drive` at `D:\MyCompany`. Is there a way for the `GetWebConfiguration` methods to look at a directory other than the default `applicationHost.Config` directory for the config files?

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. Thanks for any help, and let me know if something isn't clear. Thank you.

Comment: You can look at this link: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.getwebconfiguration?view=iis-dotnet` Seems like you just need to provide the web app name: `ServerManager.GetWebConfiguration("WEB APP NAME")`

Comment: Install IIS Administration API on those IIS machines so that you can call REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/ `Microsoft.Web.Administration` is in general not designed for .NET Core.

Comment: @kristech That's exactly what I'm doing - I provide the "APP NAME" or "SITE NAME" to the GetWebConfiguration method on the ServerManager object, but I receive the "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException," and it's because it's looking in this directory for the web.config: MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/SITE", but my web.config is actually located in a folder under my D drive. The code explicitly checks MACHINE/WEBROOT directory though, and I don't know why.

Comment: @LexLi I've been browsing the source code of IIS Administration API. I'm doing things similar except remotely. I'm trying to avoid having to install that API/microservice on over 20 servers...

Comment: You probably cannot do 'remotely" as Microsoft's code did not indicate the feasibility.

Comment: @LexLi You can do this remotely... There's an OpenRemote() method on the ServerManager object. I'm able to get the websites, apps, etc from remote IIS servers, but it's just this GetWebConfiguration method that doesn't work because I'm not storing my web.config in the directory they're checking.